# firebase functions running in development mode but not in production mode

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, production-environment

I had planned to deploy a react js app which is built by using the firebase database. It was running smoothly in development but while setting the environment to production it stucks while loading.
Note: Firebase api-keys,auth-domain, etc. are given correctly.

This is my config.js file

```
const environments = {
  development: {
   firebase: {
     apiKey: <my_api_key>,
     authDomain: <my_auth_domain>,
     databaseURL: <my_database_url>,
     projectId: <my_project_id>,
     storageBucket: <my_storage_bucket>,
     messagingSenderId: <my_messaging_sender_id>
   },
   adminServer: {
     url: <url>
   }
 },  
production: {  
  firebase: {  
    apiKey: <my_api_key>,  
    authDomain: <my_auth_domain>,  
    databaseURL: <my_database_url>,  
    projectId: <my_project_id>,  
    storageBucket: <my_storage_bucket>,  
    messagingSenderId: <my_messaging_sender_id>  
  },  
  adminServer: {  
    url: <url>  
  }  
 }  
};  

const active_env = environments.production;

export default active_env;
```

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: no error messages..the firebase phone authentication function not running. & just tested..no other firebase.ref() functions are running as well..